# React - transfer props to variable that's already a React element

Tags: reactjs

Assume you have a code:

```
const method = Component => {
  const someProps = { foo: 'bar' };
  // Add those props to the Component and render it
};
```

And you use it like this:

```
method(<MyComponent />)
```

What should I put in `method` so I can pass the `someProps` further?

Answer (score 2):

Class-based syntax

```
render() {
  return <Component {...this.props}>;
}
```

Functional based syntax

```
const method = Component => {
  const someProps = { foo: 'bar' };
  return <Component {...someProps} />;
};
```

If you wish to find out more on this topic, it's aka HOC, higher order component

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this piece code will not return a component for rendering:

```
const method = Component => {
  const someProps = { foo: 'bar' };
  // Add those props to the Component and render it
};
```

You want your [HOC](https://reactpatterns.com/#higher-order-component) `method` to be like this:

```
const method = Component => props => {
  const someProps = { foo: 'bar' }

  return <Component {...someProps} {...props} />
}
```

`...someProps` is the extra props that is 'injected' into `Component` through HOC. Usually this comes from some API calls inside HOC `method`.

While `...props` is the 'normal' props that is passed down into `Component` when calling it.

To illustrate what I meant:

```
import FooComponent from './FooComponent'

// Using the HOC:
const FooComponentWithMethod = method(FooComponent)

// ...rest of code
render() {
  return <FooComponent hello={'world'} />
}
// ...rest of code
```

When you `console.log(this.props` in `FooComponent`, you will see both

```
{
  foo: 'bar', // injected by 'method' HOC
  hello: 'world' // passed down from parent
}
```

Comment: I know how to HOCs work and how they should be structured, but I'm trying to overwrite a method that I have from a npm package, and trying not to change the behaviour of how I should pass the Component to it

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the morning brought the answer:

To get this `Component` with new props, and to keep the old one as well:

```
const method = (Component) => {
  const customProps = { foo: 'bar' };
  const elemProps = Component.props;
  const mergedProps = { ...customProps, ...elemProps };
  const cloned = React.cloneElement(Component, mergedProps);
};
```

Comment: Now I understand what you meant! Learnt something new today! Thanks!